# clang failed with exit code 254 only for iOS device target

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, llvm-4.0

I have an ios xcode project, that compile and running fine for simulator but failed to compile for device target.

I am trying to port a QT project to iOS and my project setup is quite complex. The desktop version is totally working fine and I didn't change any code except removed all UI related code.

I already file a bug report to apple (problem id:12103227) but just wondering anyone seen similar problem before?

I am using Xcode 4.4.1(4F1003) and Apple LLVM compiler 4.0

```
0  clang             0x00000001010536f2 main + 17107682
1  clang             0x0000000101053b79 main + 17108841
2  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff8f08592a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_c.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 18446603338116474608
4  clang             0x0000000100e9e31f main + 15316751
5  clang             0x00000001002d9be3 main + 2977747
6  clang             0x000000010028061d main + 2611725
7  clang             0x0000000100280237 main + 2610727
8  clang             0x0000000100280168 main + 2610520
9  clang             0x00000001001e5bdf main + 1978319
10 clang             0x00000001001df8e4 main + 1952980
11 clang             0x00000001001df55e main + 1952078
12 clang             0x00000001001b8dff main + 1794543
13 clang             0x00000001001cf06b main + 1885275
14 clang             0x00000001001ca32d main + 1865501
15 clang             0x00000001001ca1f5 main + 1865189
16 clang             0x00000001001ca0dd main + 1864909
17 clang             0x0000000100197dfc main + 1659372
18 clang             0x000000010018a31d main + 1603341
19 clang             0x0000000100047606 main + 281078
20 clang             0x0000000100045bbe main + 274350
21 clang             0x0000000100044c01 main + 270321
22 clang             0x0000000100019ae2 main + 93906
23 clang             0x0000000100018748 main + 88888
24 clang             0x0000000100006438 main + 14376
25 clang             0x0000000100002e97 main + 647
26 clang             0x0000000100002c04
27 clang             0x00000000000000a3
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple thumbv7-apple-ios5.1.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name clientplayer.cpp -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -target-abi apcs-gnu -target-cpu cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi soft -target-feature +soft-float-abi -target-linker-version 133.3 -g -coverage-file /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/Objects-normal/armv7/clientplayer.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.0 -dependency-file /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/Objects-normal/armv7/clientplayer.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -iquote /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/QSanguosha-ios-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/QSanguosha-ios-project-headers.hmap -D DEBUG=1 -D QT_GUI_LIB -D QT_NETWORK_LIB -D QT_CORE_LIB -D QT_SHARED -D Q_WS_IOS -I /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/QSanguosha-ios-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/QSanguosha-ios-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtCore -I ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtNetwork -I ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include -I include -I src/client -I src/core -I src/dialog -I src/package -I src/scenario -I src/server -I src/ui -I src/util -I src/lua -I src/jsoncpp/include -I include/freetype -I . -I /usr/local/include -I /System/Library/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers -I ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/mkspecs/macx-xcode -I /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/xiliangchen/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -F/Users/xiliangchen/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -F/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/9s/3z214w8n5vxdv_ycqss9t6jc0000gn/T/clang-module-cache -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wc++11-extensions -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-conversion -std=gnu++11 -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-runtime-has-terminate -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fsjlj-exceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/Objects-normal/armv7/clientplayer.dia -o /Users/xiliangchen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QSanguosha-bpsvweybikzifuarrculsvqhjwqj/Build/Intermediates/QSanguosha-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/QSanguosha-ios.build/Objects-normal/armv7/clientplayer.o -x c++ /Users/xiliangchen/Documents/project/QSanguosha/src/client/clientplayer.cpp 
1.  <eof> parser at end of file
2.  Code generation
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Users/xiliangchen/Documents/project/QSanguosha/src/client/clientplayer.cpp'.
4.  Running pass 'ARM Instruction Selection' on function '@_ZN15QBasicAtomicInt5derefEv'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/9s/3z214w8n5vxdv_ycqss9t6jc0000gn/T/clientplayer-diYdeq.ii
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/9s/3z214w8n5vxdv_ycqss9t6jc0000gn/T/clientplayer-diYdeq.sh
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Comment: I had a similar problem (failure that said please submit a bugreport) and it got fixed in a few months but obviously not overnight. If you can somehow create a build that does not use Xcode but is command line only using clang (a huge amount of work for sure), you can post on llvm site and maybe get a faster response. Its also possible to shoe-horn in a newer version of llvm into Xcode but again work (if it got fixed in a point release of llvm). Did you try Xcode 4.5, just to see if its fixed there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the header file Qt used for atomic variable linked to ppc header instead of armv7. The ppc header contains some inline assembly code and crashed the cross compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I had "clang failed with exit code 254 only for iOS device target". It was a strange one since I have 2 targets (for free and paid for versions of the app). One target had the error and to fix I had to change the build settings architecture to armv7. The other targer archived without a problem on armv6. Maybe something to do with Admob lib as that's the only difference between the 2 targets.